# Can't change Angular2 Material MatChip selected state

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to change [MatChip](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/api#MatChip) selected property? I wan't on click to select/deselect chip (also it have to change chip color.)
What I tried:

*html*:

```
<mat-chip-list>
   <mat-chip *ngFor="let label of item.labels" 
             #lbl (click)="selectChip(lbl)">
      {{label}}
   </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

*ts*:

```
selectChip(item: MatChip) {
   item.selected ? item.deselect() : item.select();
}
```

On click it throws

> ERROR TypeError: item.select is not a function

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a select() or deselect() method, there is just the selected getter and setter functions, so you can solve it like this:

```
selectChip(item: MatChip) {
   item.selected = !item.selected;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you use this html (please notice **#lbl="matChip"**):

```
<mat-chip-list>
   <mat-chip *ngFor="let label of item.labels" 
             #lbl="matChip" (click)="selectChip(lbl)">
      {{label}}
   </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

Your `selectChip` method will receive a MatChip and then you can do the following:

```
selectChip(item: MatChip) {
   item.toggleSelected();
}
```