# Angular Material Mat-chip selected color change

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have been trying to trigger a background color change on a mat-chip when the user selects it. Have been able toggle the state of the chip by following this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47219078/cant-change-angular2-material-matchip-selected-state](http://Mat-Chip%20Toggle)

Not much mention about it anywhere.
This is what I have so far:

```
<mat-chip-list formControlName="packageName">
  <mat-basic-chip *ngFor="let pkg of packages" #lbl selected="false" (click)="selectedPkg(lbl)">
    {{pkg.cbsCode}}<br>
  </mat-basic-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

TS

```
  selectedPkg(pkg: MatChip) {
    pkg.selected = !pkg.selected;
    pkg.color='warn';
    console.log(pkg.value);
    // this.form.patchValue({packageName: pkg});
  }
```

Comment: The problem is for the selected attr, only the color changes if the selected property is true. If you need to change the "grey" in a non selected state for your chip, you need to change the material theme or, apply manually a css style

Comment: @Kalamarico Could you provide an example on how to do it with the selected property to true.

Comment: take a look, I get and modify the angular material example, see the html: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqodwo As you can see, the first item has the color attribute, but not the selected to true so color it's not applied. In the second item, it has the color and the selected to true, so the style is applied.

Comment: If it's not clear, you can add to stackblitz your code and paste here the url and I can modify

Comment: Thanks Kalamarico for putting it up on StackBlitz, Just wondering how the code would be if the chip items are loaded up through a for loop and when the user selects a chip there, change the color of that selected chip.

Comment: Without testing your code, what I see is, when selectedPkg is executed, probably the selected property it's true, and you are setting false again, due to that the color never changes, but I can't be sure without testing it, by this I mentioned, it would be usefull if you provide a jsfiddle or stackblitz or something to see "in action" your code

Comment: @Kalamarico, Here is the link [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqodwo-81vyrs)

Comment: Ok, during this morning I will check it, I will tell you when I can

Comment: Okay thanks Kalamarico

Comment: Sorry for the delay I had not free time this day, I will check tomorrow, promise. By the way, one thing I was thinking. About the Material Chips. Have you checked what say the material guidelines about chips? It's true that they can be "selected" by not in the way that I think you are doing, like a list of elements that can be selected (for example like items of a shopping cart you know?). It's true that it's possible, but take a look to the guidelines. I think material cards will fit in your case, but I don't know. Anyway, I will check tomorrow ;)

Comment: Take a look to this example, this is the way for the "best use" to use chips as part of a selection (according Material). https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips Combine mat-input and mat-chips, so you can write (and in the example it's not implemented but you can use autocomplete for best UX) in the input and hit enter to "select" the item (chip)

Comment: Sure will check it out and update you soon.

Comment: Hey Kalamarico. I have made it to work to this point. The only thing that i couldn't get to work is deselect the previously selected chip when another chip is selected from the section. Here is it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpud2a

Comment: I don't understand the problem sorry, can you be more specific?

Comment: On that code, when you select a chip it turns to green. When you select another chip the previously selected chip is still green, I want only one chip selected at a time.